# how to show assigned role for a user in profile page the "Manage your account" in identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

how to show an assigned role for a user in the "Manage your account" page in  identity

I'm trying to show the assigned role for user in "Manage your account" I stuck at the "LoadAsync" line in this block:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        var role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        await LoadAsync(user);
        return Page();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to show an assigned role for a user in the "Manage your account" page in identity

To achieve the above requirement, you can try to modify the code as below.

```
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

public IndexModel(
    UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
    SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _signInManager = signInManager;
}

public string Username { get; set; }

public string Userroles { get; set; }

[TempData]
public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public InputModel Input { get; set; }

public class InputModel
{
    [Phone]
    [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

private async Task LoadAsync(IdentityUser user)
{
    var userName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
    var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);

    Username = userName;

    Userroles = String.Join(", ", (await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user)).ToList());

    Input = new InputModel
    {
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber
    };
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    await LoadAsync(user);
    return Page();
}
```

On page view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Userroles"></label>
    <input asp-for="Userroles" class="form-control" disabled />
</div>
```

Test Result

[image]